# Trying to implement favicon in Parallels Desktop

Tags: html, visual-studio, favicon, parallels

I am creating a website. I have tried to add a favicon. I have created a folder in Visual Studio in the Solutions Explorer named images and placed my image named "KS-final.png" in it. It did not work so I added another folder in the Project folder in which my solution is saved, named it images. The file path is \Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite1 and I have tried that as well. Should I even make a website on a Macbook using Parallels at this point? Seems a bit complicated, rather just go the full PC route. Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="imaages/KS-final.png">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    This is the content of the document
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly a typo: `href="imaages/KS-final.png"` with two As. If you're just trying to create a plain static HTML/CSS website, you don't need Windows for that. You can use any text editor (Visual Studio Code, Sublime etc.) on Mac OS directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I revised it and still no luck. I will try to move it all onto Atom and see what sticks. Will follow up soon. Thanks! @tehwalris

Comment: Edit: Well, the good news is I moved it all over to Atom and it worked perfectly fine... Weird. So I will stop using Visual Studio. @tehwalris

Comment: I've made my comment into an answer, which you can accept. That way the question will be marked as "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on my comment, which helped resolve the issue.

There is a typo in `href="imaages/KS-final.png"`, but that may not be the only thing causing the issue.

Visual Studio in a virtual machine is a relatively complex environment. That makes it hard to understand what's going wrong as a beginner. Try using a plain text editor (Visual Studio Code, Sublime, Atom etc.) on Mac OS directly. That's all you need to make a static HTML/CSS/JS website.